# Expo app crashes right upon opening in android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

when i do the npm run android, the app works just fine, but when i compile it into apk (which is being built successfully) then when i run it the app crashes.

the other raised question solutions doesn't seem to solve the problem!

app.json

```
`{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AgriApp",
    "slug": "AgriApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode":"contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.AgriAPP.AgriAPP",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
       }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "2da3b6b9-d9fb-47d9-b0b1-fae65f387b52"
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": { 
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

package.json

```
`{
  "name": "agriapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
`
```

Output : Want build and run the app on the android without being crashed

Answer (score 1):

You need to install other additional dependencies :

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 0):

**The error:**  [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install & cd ..).

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler
```

**Make sure to import 'react-native-gesture-handler' On the first line of your App.js code**